# How do I position 3 images on a 1 big image left, two small one on top of the other on right?

Tags: graphics, floats, includegraphics

I'm trying to position 3 images, one big one on the left, and 2 smaller ones on top of each other on the right, like:

[image]

I have the following code and though it works, it doesn't look like it's the best way to achieve this:

```
\begin{figure}%   \minipage[b]{0.49\linewidth}
    \centering
    \subfloat[cap]{{\includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{A.jpg}
      }}
    \endminipage\hfill
    \qquad\qquad\qquad
    \minipage[b]{0.49\linewidth}
    \subfloat[cap2]{{\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{B.jpg}}}\\
        \subfloat[cap3]{{\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{C.jpg}
          }}%
        \endminipage
    \caption{Some general caption}%
    \label{fig:example}% \end{figure}
```

Comment: Do you need a caption (number and/or text) with each of the images?

Comment: A word of advice: forget having ever seen `\minipage...\endminipage`. Use `\begin{minipage}...\end{minipage}`.

Comment: @egreg would be more useful if you noted the possible problems with this.

Comment: @Skillmon With `\minipage` it's not a big deal, but with other environments the foreign syntax `\environment...\endenvironment` might give headaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose a modification of [an answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453618/4427)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}

\usepackage{showframe,lipsum} % just for the example

\newlength{\subcolumnwidth}
\newenvironment{subcolumns}[1][0.45\columnwidth]
 {\valign\bgroup\hsize=#1\setlength{\subcolumnwidth}{\hsize}\vfil##\vfil\cr}
 {\crcr\egroup}
\newcommand{\nextsubcolumn}[1][]{%
  \cr\noalign{\hfill}
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\hsize=#1\setlength{\subcolumnwidth}{\hsize}\fi
}
\newcommand{\nextsubfigure}{\vfill}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htp]

\begin{subcolumns}
  \subfloat[Caption 1]{\includegraphics[width=\subcolumnwidth]{example-image-9x16}}
\nextsubcolumn
  \subfloat[Caption 2]{\includegraphics[width=\subcolumnwidth]{example-image-a}}
\nextsubfigure
  \subfloat[Caption 3]{\includegraphics[width=\subcolumnwidth]{example-image-b}}
\end{subcolumns}

\caption{Global caption}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[!htp]

\begin{subcolumns}[0.6\textwidth]
  \subfloat[Caption 1]{\includegraphics[width=\subcolumnwidth]{example-image-1x1}}
\nextsubcolumn[0.35\textwidth]
  \subfloat[Caption 2]{\includegraphics[width=\subcolumnwidth]{example-image-a}}
\nextsubfigure
  \subfloat[Caption 3]{\includegraphics[width=\subcolumnwidth]{example-image-b}}
\end{subcolumns}

\caption{Global caption}

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering

\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{subcolumns}[0.62\textwidth]
  \subfloat[Caption 1]{\includegraphics[width=\subcolumnwidth]{example-image-1x1}}
\nextsubcolumn[0.33\textwidth]
  \subfloat[Caption 2]{\includegraphics[width=\subcolumnwidth]{example-image-a}}
\nextsubfigure
  \subfloat[Caption 3]{\includegraphics[width=\subcolumnwidth]{example-image-b}}
\end{subcolumns}
\end{minipage}

\caption{Global caption}

\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-5]

\end{document}
```

The optional argument to `\begin{subcolumns}` determines the width of the first column (default `0.45\textwidth`, good for two equal columns) and of all other columns; however, one can specify an optional argument to `\newsubcolumn` to set the width for the next column. I provided three examples just to show how it works; the last one shows how to reduce the overall size that, by default occupies the whole column width.

[image]

You can have as many columns as you want.

```latex
\begin{figure}[!htp]

\begin{subcolumns}[0.3\textwidth]
  \subfloat[Caption 1]{\includegraphics[width=\subcolumnwidth]{example-image-9x16}}
\nextsubcolumn     
  \subfloat[Caption 2]{\includegraphics[width=\subcolumnwidth]{example-image-a}}
\nextsubfigure    
  \subfloat[Caption 3]{\includegraphics[width=\subcolumnwidth]{example-image-b}}
\nextsubcolumn
  \subfloat[Caption 4]{\includegraphics[width=\subcolumnwidth]{example-image-a}}
\nextsubfigure
  \subfloat[Caption 5]{\includegraphics[width=\subcolumnwidth]{example-image-b}}
\end{subcolumns}

\caption{Global caption}

\end{figure}
```

[image]

---

#### *Aside advice*

Avoid foreign syntax such as `\minipage...\endminipage`. It's not a big deal with the specific case, but `\flushleft...\endflushleft` would be disastrous.

Answer (score 3):

The following uses the `subcaption` package and stacks the two images on the right using a `tabular` environment.

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}[c]{.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck-portrait}%
    \caption
      {%
        the big one%
        \label{fig:big}%
      }%
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{.48\linewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%
      \caption
        {%
          the upper small one%
          \label{fig:upper}%
        }%
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \noalign{\bigskip}%
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{.48\linewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,page=2]{example-image-duck}%
      \caption
        {%
          the lower small one%
          \label{fig:lower}%
        }%
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption
    {%
      The big caption for everyone%
      \label{fig:every}%
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]