# Positioning of two images at top ends of a page

Tags: graphics, positioning, subfloats, includegraphics

I have two images that I would like to place at the top edges of the document.
One image at top left and other image at top right. But I am not able to achieve it

[image]

This how it looks whereas I want both in the same line. The picture `A` at top left and picture `B` at top right of the page. The code for it as follows:

```
    \begin{figure}[t]
       \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=3cm,left]{Pictures/a.jpg}}\\
        \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=3cm,right]{Pictures/b.jpg}}\\
    \end{figure}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Looks like these links from the Related: section do what you need: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343855/two-images-with-different-size-side-by-side-automatic-computation?rq=1, and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515311/how-do-i-position-3-images-on-a-1-big-image-left-two-small-one-on-top-of-the-ot?rq=1 .

Comment: They are NOT on the same line due to the use of \\ (\newline).  By "the top edges of the document", do you mean the text area or the paper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to make them float in this case, hence you don't need the `figure` environment. Just start your document from the images

```latex
\vspace*{-\topskip}%
\noindent%
\includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=t]{example-image-a}%
\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=t]{example-image-b}
```

Additionally, the first line removes `\topskip` latex adds as the first thing on a page whilst `\noindent` cancels indentation.

Also, `\includegraphics` does not have a key `left`. Positioning in LaTeX is achieved by adding necessary space before/after/between images, even if they are inside `figure`. Conveniently, `\hfill`, equivalent of `\hspace{\fill}` adds a necessary stretch to spread both images both sides.

The full code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{-\topskip}%
\noindent%
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}%
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
\end{document}
```

---

EDIT.
In case each of the images have a different size, you might need to add the top alignment by adding `valign=t` (available with the package `adjustbox`)

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}   % <--- adds valign=t

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.2pt}
\renewcommand*{\ShowFrameColor}{\color{red}}


\begin{document}
\vspace*{-\topskip}%
\noindent%
\includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=t]{example-image-a}%
\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=t]{example-image-16x9}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,float,mwe}
\usepackage{showframe} % comment after testing
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t]
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\hfill
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}\\
    \end{figure}
\[ax^2+bx+c=0 \Rightarrow x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]